# How to know if my Recordset is full and extract it to an Excel Sheet?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm writing a macro to translate a request into an SQL query, execute it and return it on a new Excel Sheet.

The object I called "Result", should execute the query, and basically the rest of the code that should allow me to extract the data and put it on an Excel Sheet.

After researching the subject, I got the following code, which produced

> error 3021 : 'No Current Record'.

Result is an object, connection is an object (for the connection), requete is a string, which is the SQL query that should be executed.
Output is a variant. (I don't get what this is meant to be used for.)

I get the error on the line `Debug.Print Result(i-1)`.

```vb
Set Result = connection.Execute(requete)

Do
    For i = 1 To Result.Fields.Count
        Debug.Print Result(i - 1)
        Output = Output & Result(i - 1) & ";"
        Ws_res.Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset Result
    Next i
    Output = Output & vbNewLine
    Result.MoveNext
Loop Until Result.EOF
```

I researched a bit more, and it led me to "test" with .EOF first, then write the rest of the code to get my query with `GetRows()`.

```vb
If not Result.EOF Then 
    Output = Result.GetRows()
    nbcol = UBound(Output, 1) + 1
    For i = 1 To Result.Fields.Count
        For j = 1 To nbcol
            Debug.Print Output(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Ws_res.Cells(1, 1) = Output
Else
    MsgBox ("No Data found")
End If
```

This code runs, but it always gets me "No Data Found". So I'm stuck on this as I can't know if the first bit works.

I don't know where the problem comes from, the code, the recordset or the query?

Here is the whole function (I've updated the bit that causes me a problem with what was suggested, but I have again the 3021 error):

```vb
Function fct_resultat(fichier_type As Integer, Sql As String, rgD As Range) As Variant
 
Dim connection As Object
Dim Result As Object
Dim SaveName As Variant
Dim Wb_Res As Workbook
Dim Ws_res As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim nbcol As Integer, nbrow As Integer
Dim requete As String

Set Wb_Res = Workbooks.Add
Set Ws_res = Wb_Res.Worksheets(1)
 
Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With connection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .connectionstring = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With

requete = Sql
Set Result = connection.Execute(requete)

Do
    Ws_res.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Result
    Result.MoveNext
Loop Until Result.EOF
```

Additionally, regarding the query itself (requete), it is a string which has been built through various functions (the goal being creating a query from inputs by the user). Therefore, it is a variable string, defined earlier in the code (I have a function for my sql_string and a function to execute the query).

Here is an example of the sql query string (I'm French, which explains all the details in French):

```
SELECT bps_codeFonds, Portefeuille, bps_libellePaysEmetteur,
       bps_libTypeInstr, bps_libSousTypeInstr, id_inventaire,
       bps_pruDevCot
FROM [Donnees$] 
WHERE bps_deviseCotation="DKK"  AND 
      bps_quantite<10000 
ORDER BY AuM ASC;
```

I am quite familiar with VBA and SQL, but it is my first time handling objects that should connect the two languages.

Comment: Only one line required `Ws_res.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset connection.Execute(requete)`

Comment: `NextRecordset` is only used if your query returns multiple recordsets: you can ignore that direction.  The only test you really need is `If Result.EOF` - if that's true then your query returned no records.  If you use `CopyFromRecordset` then that reads the whole recordset in one shot - after you've called that your recordset cursor will be left at the end of the records, so you can't access any records unless you first call (eg) `MoveFirst` to re-position the cursor.  Might be useful to update your question to add the full code, including your variable declarations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer ! For the test with If Result.EOF, it seems like my query returned no record then ? If so, do you have any idea of what I have done wrong and how I could modify the code so I can get my data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    fct_resultat "select * from [Donnees$] where false"
End Sub

'Your Function returns no result, so make it a Sub...
Sub fct_resultat(Sql As String)

    Dim connection As Object, Result As Object, SaveName As Variant
    Dim Wb_Res As Workbook, Ws_res As Worksheet
    
    Set Wb_Res = Workbooks.Add
    Set Ws_res = Wb_Res.Worksheets(1)
     
    Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With connection
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .connectionstring = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
        Set Result = .Execute(Sql)
    End With
    
    If Not Result.EOF Then
        'This copies the content of the entire recordset,
        ' so there's no need to use it in a loop 
        Ws_res.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset Result
    Else
        Ws_res.Range("A1").Value = "No results"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

If your specific SQL is not returning any results, you need to check your data to make sure it actually has matching records.